# Clustering lists based on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, hierarchical-clustering, dbscan

If we have a input of a dictionary with format {key: [list]} like below

```
List1: [value01, value02, value 03]
List2: [value02, value04, value 05]
List3: [value04, value05, value 07]
```

- The values are strings

Is there a way where we can group/cluster the keys (list names ) based on the similarity between it's values(lists) in python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It really depends on how you want to cluster them. Whether you want to remove all repetitions of values or cluster keys together based on a certain percentage of similarity between their values. There are likely many different structures which would "cluster the keys" but without a concrete explanation there's no way to know which ones to use.

Comment: Agreed , for my use case it will be the to cluster keys together based on certain percentage of similarity Between their values which are going to be deduplicated. Any way/clustering algorithm can you suggest for this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

Really sorry for the late answer, I'm not a frequent user of SO.

To group by percentage a function like so should do the trick:

```
import difflib

def cluster(seq_matcher, input_dict, percentage):
 joined_dict = {key : "".join(values) for key, values in input_dict.items()}
 all_values = tuple(joined_dict.values())
 for i, key in enumerate(joined_dict):
  values = joined_dict[key]
  if any(seq_matcher(values, other_values) >= percentage for other_values in all_values[:i]):
   joined_dict[key] = 0
 return {key : values for key, values in input_dict.items() if joined_dict[key]}

seq_matcher = lambda x, y: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).ratio() * 100
cluster(seq_matcher, input_dict, 60)
```

One of the best ways to compare iterables in python is using the difflib module as described below. Of course, different sequence matchers have different key features which you want so to use, so  to change the algorithm which determines the percentage similarity between your lists of values you can change the seq_matcher function.

I recommend the difflib sequence matcher because it's the best algorithm in terms of comparing objects the way a human would.

You can also change the percentage argument to, as you can probably imagine, change the percentage cutoff for keys.

Hope this helps!